# how to close two window forms in a single click in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two window form opened at the same time. Inside the form 1, there is a button and I want to close both active forms by clicking that button. Please help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried handler.

Comment: do you open form 2 after form 1 is open?

Comment: In the `FormClosing` event of form A also close form B with something like `formB.Close()`.

Comment: You can try Application.OpenForms to get open forms. And you can loop it to close. But the main form stays open.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to store a reference to the other Form and then have:

```
otherForm.Close();
this.Close();
```

in the Button's `Click` event handler method.

In case one is the Parent of the other you can also have

```
this.Close();
((this.Parent) as Form).Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter how many forms you have, create some custom event that will be a trigger to close some of you current forms. Then subscribe on this event inside forms that you want to close and after event is happened just call `this.Close()`.

Answer (score 1):

`button1` is the button which close both forms.

```
public partial class TieableForm : Form
{
    public TieableForm() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private Form Other { get; set; }

    public void Tie(Form other) =>
        Other = other;

    public void Untie() =>
        Other = null;

    private void button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        CloseBoth();

    private void CloseBoth()
    {
        if (Other != null)
            Other.Close();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
TieableForm tf = new TieableForm();
Form f = new Form();
tf.Tie(f);
f.Show();
tf.Show();
```

**Warning!**
Using this solution will not close both forms if you close the `TieableForm` by the *normal way*!

> Inside the form 1, there is a button and I want to close both active forms by clicking that button.

Answer (score 0):

`this.Close()`  or  `Application.Exit()` can be used to close a windows form.  As you have two windows you will want to use `Application.Exit()` see msdn link for more information

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit(v=vs.110).aspx

A brutal way of closing the two windows could be to run `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();` but this will be the same as killing the process in task explorer.

Comment: Wrong Application.Exit() will close whole application and this.close() will close current form.

Comment: they 'can be used to close form'... ie they will have the effect of closing the windows form, agreed though 1 only closes current form and other closes whole application

Answer (score -1):

First if You Try To close **Form 2** from **Form 1** Then You Have to Create Object of **Form 2** in **Form 1** because The Close event on **Form 1**

Object Create On Form 1

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(); // This is global object

frm2.show(); // this is function or onload event or constructor
```

on Form 1 Closing Event or Button Event

```
// do all this in form closing event or button
frm2.close();
frm2.dispose();
```

Comment: whats wrong in this? Why you vote down?